# cassandra cql delete using a less than operator on a secondary key

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have a table similar to this

```
{
  CREATE TABLE timeseries (
    event_type text,
    insertion_time timestamp,
    event blob,
    PRIMARY KEY (event_type, insertion_time)
  )
}
```

and I am trying to do

```
delete * from timseries where event_type='xxx' and insertion_time <'12345';
```

Bad Request: Invalid operator LT for PRIMARY KEY part insertion_time.

Does cassandra support these kind of deletes ? 
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

No, range deletes are not supported.

For what is support, look at the CQL3 documentation:

http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping that I missed something in documentation.

Answer (score 6):

Note that range deletes (on the cluster key) are in the next major version (3.0-beta2). Patch got committed to trunk just recently: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6237

Answer (score 4):

do a select first, then delete each result.